# find match between random lists as fast as possible in fortran (+openmp)

Tags: performance, loops, fortran, openmp

I have two lists, I need to match elements in one against the other and output those elements into a new matrix (output). What is the fastest way to this in Fortran? Brute force so far:

```
do i = 1,Nlistone
   do j = 1,Nlisttwo
     if A(i).eq.B(j) then
        output(i) = B(j)
     end if
   end do
end do
```

openmp version:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i,j)
do i = 1,NA
   do j = 1,NB
     if A(i).eq.B(j) then
        filtered(i) = A(j)
     end if
   end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

There are definitely better ways to do this and sorting is not an option here sorry (+ the vector elements are not in any particular order). Is there a boolean argument similar to `mask` in python?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't exit the inner loop once a match is found?

Comment: I need one CONTINUE statement under filtered(i) = ... ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - High Performance Mark, Hristo Iliev and Ian Bush seem to be the people consistently posting excellent help (I'm sure there are others). Are you employed by stackoverflow or just good Samaritans?

Comment: I doubt if Stack Exchange employs anyone to post answers here :)

Comment: @Griff Continue is essentially a NOP in Fortran. Exit is what you need under that line. And no, I don't work for stackoverflow, but thanks for your kind words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be faster to use the intrinsic `ANY` function something like this

```
do i = 1,Nlistone
     if (any(B==A(i))) output(i) = A(i)
end do
```

but I wouldn't bet on this improving performance, I'd test both versions.  You should be able to safely wrap this inside an `!$OMP PARALLEL DO` construct since each element of `output` is only written to by one thread.

Comment: My original omp doesn't seem to work:  filtered(i) = A(j)
Error: !$OMP ATOMIC assignment must have an operator or intrinsic on right hand side at (1) Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the condition testing in a `forall` or (newer) `do concurrent` construct, which both use the same syntax:

```
do concurrent(i = 1:Nlistone, any(a(i) == b)) 
  output(i) = a(i)
end do
```

This might be faster than your code listing, depending on the nature `A` and `B`. But it still has the same time complexity of O(n^2), while sorting can be O(n*log(n)). If `Nlistone /= Nlisttwo`, you could gain a factor equal to the ratio of these sizes, by only looping through the shorter array and matching its elements to the longer one.